# Passing hash to #new results in array of values instead of correct value

Tags: ruby

With this setup in minitest,

```
 def test_id
    i = Item.new({
      :id          => 1,
      :name        => "Pencil",
      :description => "You can use it to write things",
      :unit_price  => BigDecimal.new(10.99,4),
      :created_at  => Time.now,
      :updated_at  => Time.now,
      :merchant_id => 2
                    })
    assert_equal 1, i.id  
end
```

For some reason, when created, calling the `id` attribute results in an array of all of the values:
`[1,'Pencil','You can use it to write things',#<BigDecimal...>, 2018-07-24 14:43:36 -0600, 2018-07-24 14:43:36 -0600, 2]`

instead of the integer `1`.

In the item file, it looks like what you would expect

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'time'

    class Item
      attr_reader :id, :created_at, :merchant_id
      attr_accessor :name, :description, :unit_price, :updated_at

      def initialize(item_data)
        @id =           item_data[:id].to_i,
        @name =         item_data[:name],
        @description =  item_data[:description],
        @unit_price =   BigDecimal.new(item_data[:unit_price], 4),
        @created_at =   item_data[:created_at],
        @updated_at =   item_data[:updated_at],
        @merchant_id =  item_data[:merchant_id].to_i
      end
    end
```

Not really sure how this is happening.

Throwing a `pry` in the test method before the assertion and calling `i` results in

```
#<Item:0x00007f8cc48eb4f0
 @created_at=2018-07-24 15:14:55 -0600,
 @description="You can use it to write things",
 @id=[1, "Pencil", "You can use it to write things", #<BigDecimal:7f8cc48eb4c8,'0.1099E2',18(27)>, 2018-07-24 15:14:55 -0600, 2018-07-24 15:14:55 -0600, 2],
 @merchant_id=2,
 @name="Pencil",
 @unit_price=#<BigDecimal:7f8cc48eb4c8,'0.1099E2',18(27)>,
 @updated_at=2018-07-24 15:14:55 -0600>
```

in the terminal.

Comment: Post a [mcve]. It's hard to tell what's happening, if we can't reproduce.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I updated the question. All it's doing is running that `test_id` test in minitest. Putting a `pry ` in at the end of the end of the `initialize` and calling  `@id` or `id` results in the array posted in the question. Or calling `i.id` in the test method results in the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your trailing commas in the initializer:

```
def initialize(item_data)
  @id =           item_data[:id].to_i, # <=
  @name =         item_data[:name],    # <=
```

What they do is make ruby see the method like this:

```
 @id = [item_data[id].to_i, @name = item_data[:name], ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem are the commas that you are adding at the end of each setting variable. Check with this code:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'time'

class Item
  attr_reader :id, :created_at, :merchant_id
  attr_accessor :name, :description, :unit_price, :updated_at

  def initialize(item_data)
    @id =           item_data[:id].to_i
    @name =         item_data[:name]
    @description =  item_data[:description]
    @unit_price =   BigDecimal.new(item_data[:unit_price], 4)
    @created_at =   item_data[:created_at]
    @updated_at =   item_data[:updated_at]
    @merchant_id =  item_data[:merchant_id].to_i
  end
end
```